# Crypt int into 4-char String

Tags: php, math, encryption

I'd like to crypt a int up to 7'000'000 into a 4-char string and then decrypt back.

Any idea on how this can be easy be achieved with php?

**Clarification**

I want to create a unique slug for each Wordpress user based on the user ID with a length of 4 chars.

example.com/rDfy

Comment: Unless you know something about quantum mechanics and the pigeonhole principle then it's not happening...

Comment: @l'L'l How come? All I need to to is convert a number with base 10 to a number base 52 using all the letters in the alphabet

Comment: @l'L'l log2(7,000,000) = 22.7 bits or < 3 full bytes.

Comment: @zaph: but then log2(6999999.99) would not be distinguished from log2(7000000)

Comment: @l'L'l l'm not suggestion to use math, just demonstrating that the amount of information is less than 23 bits. Note the question states: "into a 4-char string".

Comment: The 7M don't really matter, I just need to convert the int into a 4 char string and as far as I know a unique string can be achieved until the number  7'311'616 (52^4)

Comment: Sorry bout the typo in the title

Comment: encryption is not possible with that big number, but encoding must be

Comment: How come? Using case-sensitive letters from the alphabet offers 7'311'616 unique combinations

Comment: @MichaelCool: If you are not talking about **encryption** but rather *encoding*, then yes - you can encode the number for example in hexadecimal: `7000001 = 6ACFC1`, which is three bytes in size; encryption is not the same thing as encoding...

Comment: That's a great hint! Is it possible to generate a 6-char hexadecimal also for smaller numbers like 3?

Comment: @MichaelCool: Well you could represent `3` in hex like `00000003` I suppose.

Comment: @MichaelCool: Also characters and bytes are different terms — for example in hexadecimal `41` is one byte, which would represent the `A` character in ascii, and the number `65` in decimal...

Comment: I've updated my post to clarify what I actually need

Answer (score 0):

log2(7,000,000) = 22.7 or < 3 full bytes. Make the value a 4-byte integer and then cast it to a 4-byte array and Base64 encode the least significant 3 bytes to 4-bytes, that is an encoding, not encryption but may suffice.

If you need encryption then encrypt the byte array using a substitution cipher, sure it is not strong encryption.